# What's the name of this output connector of ac adaptor

Tags: ac, connector, output

What's the name of this output connector of ac adaptor :
[image: connector ac adaptor]

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[That's a DIN 41529 loudspeaker connector.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector#Loudspeaker_connector)

It's simple, it's polarized, so it was only a matter of time the Chinese used it for LED lighting power connectors.

Comment: + it was already lying in stock in millions after decades of usage as standard audio connector, where it has been becoming less and less popular over the last three decades.

Comment: the polarization would make sense if that transformer was an impedance converter in an audio amp, but in an AC adapter - there is no rectifier?

Comment: @dlatika: They use these for DC power supplies, too.

Comment: i didn't know about the LED's, but Ikea, among others, have used it for decades for their halogen lamp power supplies.

Comment: happy to see this pushed you over the "magic" 1k boundary :) next step is getting you enough reputation that you can fix things in questions.

Comment: Erm, I do not believe in editing other people's posts. Sorry. Actually I think of giving away reputation for bounties, that's the only good use I can think of.